# What is the depth of comparator circuit required in Gale Shapely and STCONN?

Tags: complexity-theory, sorting, complexity-classes, circuits, matching

Stable matching problem and $STCONN$ can be solved using comparator circuits (refer https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2721).

1. What is the depth of the $CC$ circuit necessary for stable matching? Is it in $CC^1$ or in other words $O(\log (n))$ depth comparator circuit?
2. What is the depth of the $CC$ circuit necessary for $NL$? Is it in $CC^1$ or in other words $O(\log (n))$ depth comparator circuit?

Notice $STCONN$ is complete for $NL$ and is in $AC^1\subseteq NC^2$ which perfect matching (not stable) is in $NC^2$ and is hard for $NL$.

If 1. and 2. and not in $CC^1$ then what is the minimum $CC^i$ upper bound?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the proofs in the paper? They give some upper bounds. You shouldn't expect any lower bounds, since non-trivial lower bounds are difficult. State-of-the-art lower bounds can be found in Gál and Robere, [Lower Bounds for (Non-monotone) Comparator Circuits](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2019/128/)

Comment: I tried looking at the paper. I have no idea of what the upper bounds are. I am not seeking lower bounds.

Comment: When I think of $NC$ I think of $NC^k$ at a particular $k$. The $NL$ reduction to $CC$ illustrated on pp. $35$ in https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2721 for $n=5$ has at least $5$ layers and so depth for general $n$ is not appearing to be $polylogarithmic$. I similarly do not get insight for perfect matching.

Comment: All the information you need is in the paper. It might require some work extracting it.

Comment: The section on $NL\subseteq CC$ on pp. $35$ is straightforward but I still do not really see depth to be $o(n)$.